# How to configure VSCode for debugging React-Native with chrome debugging tools?

Tags: react-native, configuration, visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

I'd like some simple steps for beginners on how to properly accomplish this for react-native. There are tutorials for Reactjs, and for Angular but not for react-native and it's proving difficult to accomplish.

Comment: See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: Read through it, what should I set `REACT_DEBUGGER` to for vscode for react-native?

Comment: Maybe https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.vscode-react-native is what you're looking for?